# WebView shows only white although delegate is set and methods are being called

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a viewcontroller that loads a webView in the view did load

```
@synthesize webView = _webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    [self.webView setDelegate:self];
    NSString *string = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"The URL is %@", url);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"The request is %@", request);
    NSLog(@"webview delegate is %@", self.webView.delegate);
    NSLog(@"webview is %@", self.webView);
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Everything is working fine when i debug meaning that nothing is returning nil. I declared the property in the .h file like this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

I have also tried

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

and the WebView in IB is hooked up to delegate and this property. The problem is that no matter what url I try (I have tried them all in the browser), the web view only returns a white screen. All the delegate methods have been called, I know because I logged to the console. Does anyone know how to fix this or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You aren't adding the webView to your root view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code -

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

Since you are connected webview to an outlet, the instance of webview is created after the unarchiving of your Nib.

So no need to instantiate webview again -

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
```

Remove the above line from your code and test it. Should work!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the fix for this issue seems to me pretty straightforward.

You're not setting any frame for your web view. Try the following:

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,500,500)];
```

Of course, the actual dimensions for your web view may vary. You'll have to adjust it yourself.

**Update**

I'm seeing that you're not adding the web view as a subview. Add the following line after the call to `loadRequest:`

```
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it but the same results. Here is what the logs say.  The URL is http://www.google.com
The request is <NSURLRequest: 0xbb9b520> { URL: http://www.google.com }
webview delegate is <myViewController: 0xbab9a90>
webview is <UIWebView: 0xbbacfa0; frame = (384 415; 718 782); layer = <CALayer: 0xbbabf40>>
Should start to load URL
Loading Tutorial URL.....
Should start to load URL
Finished loading Tutorial URL for some reason, shouldStartLoadWithRequest is being called twice....